# How do I compare two count data and show that there is true difference between them through Bayesian statistics?

Tags: bayesian, chi-squared-test, likelihood, count-data

I have two categories : Protein and Carbohydrate denoting two type of food available in a setup. From Protein, 335 food pieces has been eaten from a total of 1095 pieces and from Carbohydrate, 70 food pieces has been eaten from 1095 pieces. The experiment is being done on dogs. At a time, a dog can eat upto 15 pieces of each food category (15+15 = 30 food pieces are provided each time and a dog can eat from both.)I have prior information from a previous experiment for both of them (Protein : 50/1020; Carbohydrate : 23/1020). I would like to compare the two categories of data while including the prior data I have. In frequentist method, I would have done a chi square goodness of fit test by assuming the expected ratio of eating from the two categories as 1:1.

All the packages in R that I found such as Bayesian first aid, Bayes factor etc. don't let us use informative priors for the test. so my questions are :

1. Is there a way to include the prior information in the chi square test formula? If yes, how?
2. If no, what sort of test should I be doing?

**Edit 1** : No. of dogs in previous experiment = 68 ; No. of dogs in current experiment = 360

**Edit 2** : The previous experiment was on individual dogs (n=68), the current experiment is on groups of dogs (n=73) of varying sizes with a total of 360 dogs across all groups. Each group is exposed to the experimental set-up once and we count the number of pieces left/eaten after each trial

I am not looking to be spoon fed each line of the code. Feel free to point me towards the right resources (blogs/articles/videos etc)

Information about me : I have been learning Bayesian stats for a month and a half now. I come from a biology background with minimal math and programming skills so math heavy explanations tend to go over my head but I am willing to learn.

Comment: Do you have information on each experimental unit (e.g. each dog)?

Comment: @DemetriPananos : Previous experiment has shown us that these free-ranging dogs (different from pet dogs) prefer protein over carbohydrate, population wise, as shown from the data I have provided (I had done a chi square goodness of fit test for that). That experiment was done on individual dogs. The current experiment is on groups of dogs. But the experimental set up is same. That is all the information we possess. Was I able to answer your question properly?

Comment: After re-reading your comment, I should add, in our previous experiment, we knew how many pieces of food each dog ate. This time we know for some dogs, not all (They have to forage and eat from garbage bins, so its not always clear to the experimenter who ate how much in the group as they all eat together)

Comment: OK, that is what I'm more interested in.  So all you know is how much the pack ate from either of the two categories.  Is that correct?

Comment: A quick glance over my data tells me I know the feeding pattern of individual members in 45/73 groups (i.e. number of food pieces they ate, if they ate at all). For the rest, yes, I only know how much the pack ate.

Comment: The fraction for the total number of pieces eaten (the sum of P and C) is very different between the "current" dataset and the "prior" dataset. What is your *model* for how the data are generated? In other words, what is the likelihood? Here's another way to ask what I'm trying to get at: How would I go about simulating data like yours?

Comment: Another question: You say "At a time, a dog can eat upto 15 pieces of each food category (15+15 = 30 food pieces are provided each time and a dog can eat from both.)" - do you have that break-down by occurences (and, I suppose, dogs?)? As @mef suggests, the ideal set-up for any analysis (whether Bayesian or not) is that you can specify how the data came about in an idealized way.

Comment: E.g. dog i on occasion j can eat <=15 pieces of P & <=15 of C. Let's assume that's based on the "dog greediness" g_i, the hungriness a_{ij} (how hungry this dog is on this occasion) and the "preferring P over C"-parameter b_i  for dog i. Assume occasions are pretty far apart so that we do not need to worry about a dog still being full from one occasion at the next one. We might also assume P_{ij} ~ truncated Poisson( exp(mu + +g_i + b_i + a_{ij})) and P_{ij} ~ truncated Poisson( exp(mu + g_i + a_{ij})), where the g_i, b_i and a_{ij} are normally distributed random effects. Sound plausible?

Comment: @mef : I am thinking Poisson distribution with gamma priors. The priors for chicken (50,68) ; Priors for bread (23,68), mu for chicken = 335/360 ; mu for bread = 70/360
No. of dogs in previous experiment = 68 ; No. of dogs in current experiment = 360. Is this what you were asking? I will edit the question to include the info i provided here. Apologies if I answered your question wrongly.

Comment: @Björn : 1 dog or 1 group (consisting of multiple dogs) is only allowed to do the experiment once. Single occasion, not multiple. I know the breakdown for a subset of dogs/groups (45 groups). That is, I know what each dog in those 45 groups have eaten (if they have eaten at all). For the previous experiment, I know for all 68 dogs. For the example used, I would say only "b_i" is applicable as a parameter for me. My objective is to answer the following questions : Have the Protein and Carb pieces been eaten equally (1:1)? If not, have they been eaten in the ratio in which they ... contd in next

Comment: were eaten in the previous experiment, (i.e approx 2:1)? If I can compare and show that Protein count > Carb count, I guess that also answers my question that they don't follow 1:1 trend.

Comment: I'm puzzled by some of your numbers now. 68 * 15 = 1020, but 360 * 15 = 5400, not 1095. What am I missing?

Comment: You are right, if you only have each animal once, you can distinguish between occasion and animal effects.
In any case, it would be straightforward to write down a model for this, if you had the data broken down for each dog.
The tricky bit is that the correct likelihood is hard to write down. It's possible, but very complicated and will be a computational bottleneck. You end up summing over all possible permutations of how the eaten 335 protein items & 70 carbohydrate items break down into 0 to 15 per dog & type for each of 360 dogs. That is a big # of possible configurations to sum over.

Comment: Perhaps you could solve this with Approximate Bayesian Computation, but it's definitely not a case with a nice simple answer that standard packages will cover easily (you can probably write some custom Stan code...). By the way, a frequentist chi square test is wrong due to the non-independence of the observations (both within and across food type). It's an interesting question whether there's some simple likelihood that could be used as an approximation (in either a Bayesian or frequentist maximum likelihood context), but that's not very obvious, either.

Comment: @mef : Oh no! I thought I mentioned it in the question but it was in the comments. Apologies. Rookie mistake. So the previous expt was with individual dogs. The current expt is with groups of dogs (73 groups of varying sizes, 360 dogs in total). So 73*15 = 1095, i.e. each group is exposed to the food setup once and we note down how much food is left/eaten after each trial. I know the breakdown of eating for 45 groups (as in what each member has eaten, if at all they have). I will update this in the question, right now.

Comment: @Björn : I didn't get you. Each dog has eaten only a certain number of pieces (<15 in almost all cases, and very few times from both. And not all 360 dogs have eaten). Is your statement about the possible permutations in reference to how the algorithm runs? Apologies if this an obvious point and I didn't understand that. Are you saying that in Bayesian it's very hard to check if an expected number/ratio is followed by the data? Could you also explain your non-independence point a bit more? Is it possible that instead I just show that P(Chicken) > P(bread) with Poisson-gamma comparison ..contd

Comment: as I mentioned to @mef above and because P(Chicken) > P(Bread), therefore they are not being eaten equally or following the 1:1 ratio (as mentioned in the question). I mean, all I want to see is if they are being eaten in equal amounts or not (they are not, obviously) and to show statistical proof for it.

Comment: This is really tough whether you're Bayesian or not. If you do not know the break down into dogs, then the most obvious solution would be to write down the model one would use, if one knew exactly which dog ate what. Then one sums over all possible numbers of items of each type of food each dog could have eaten. In some situations This type of approach is pretty manageable, but here it sounds painful. You can clearly code this type of model in e.g. Stan using nested function calls, but I worry it would take ages to evaluate the likelihood.

Comment: This becomes easier if I knew the breakdown for each dog? I could use a subset of the total dogs, the subset having dogs whose breakdown i know. What would I do then?